# Python Context Manager for releasing memory

Tags: python, memory-management, contextmanager

Hi guys I have a quick question about python context manager.

How do I create a context manager where it will release all memory from an array or list? Is it even possible to do something like that?

Say I have the array

```
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

We can certainly use clear or del to clear/delete the array but it will still be there in memory. And then we can use gc.collect() to clear it from memory.

```
class FileManager():
    def __init__(self, filename, mode):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode
        self.file = None
         
    def __enter__(self):
        self.file = open(self.filename, self.mode)
        return self.file
     
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        self.file.close()

with FileManager('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('Test')
```

But is it possible to create a context manager class to do this? I know they are usually used for file management as I wrote the code above...just wondering how else to use context manager

Comment: `del` does not delete an object, it deletes a name for the object. if the object has other names, it will remain in memory. and `gc.collect()` is not a step to free up memory after using `del`. you have very little real control over how memory is managed in Python; even if you manage to get Python to free memory, it probably still won't be released back to the operating system.

Comment: You can create a context manager which takes a list object and clears it (remove its content and set its length to zero) and finally calls "gc.collect" but there is no way to really force deletion of a Python object.

Comment: @MichaelButscher would I then put the clear in __enter__ ? I think I'm confused with that implementation

Comment: Sorry, I meant to clear and call "gc.collect" in `__exit__`.